# Jekyllrb /assets/images directory?

Tags: jekyll

How exactly do I add this? If I add a images directory to the assets folder it gets deleted....but most examples talk about referring to `/assets/images/whatever.jpg` to be able to access an image.

How exactly do I get a folder added?

Im using the minimal-mistakes theme (but I doubt that matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add your directory to the "source root" instead of within the `_site` folder.
The contents of `_site` gets recycled every time you run `jekyll build` or `jekyll serve`..

Simply add `assets/images/whatever.jpg` to the root of your site's source and it will be "copied" as is into `_site` by Jekyll...